# Getting "Authentication Credentials Were not Provided" when testing DRF endpoint on Locust

Tags: django, locust

I am trying to load test an endpoint that allows users to create posts using locust, it is worth mentioning that users need to be authenticated before they can access this endpoint.

**Problem:**
When I hit the endpoint using locust, I keep getting the error saying "Authentication provided were not provided" even though I have done so and I have also configured my endpoint to accept token (I am using the default DRF token feature). Any idea what I am doing wrong? any help will be appreciated. Below is my code:

**Locust file**

```
class ListPostUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task(3)
    def create_post(self):
        data = {
            "title": "This is another random title", 
            "body": "This is the body of a randomly titled post"
        }
        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Token 508e650b0ca1613818939089190a1661a75865b1"
        }
        response = self.client.post("blog/create", json=data, headers=headers)

        print(response)
        print(response.json())

    @task
    def comment_detail(self):
        self.client.get("blog/comment/1")

    @task(2)
    def post_detail(self):
        self.client.get("blog/post/1")


    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post("login/", json={"username": "username", "password": "mypassword"})
```

**views file**

```
class CreatePostAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CreatePostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I should also note that the endpoint works fine on POSTMAN, I only get the error when I am load testing with locust

Comment: `comment_detail` and `post_detail` does not set any token on the auth header, so the error might be coming from there. Did you include those tasks?

Comment: endpoints for comment_details and post_detail do not need users to be authenticated to access them, hence the reason why I did not set the token on the auth header for them.

I finally found the solution to the issue though, I needed to set the TokenAuthentication class in my settings.py file (I will post it as an answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you find the real issue, but you can investigate the exact payload sent by examining `response.request`, like this:

`print(response.request.headers)` `print(response.request.data)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to the issue, All I needed to do was add `TokenAuthentication` to the list of default authentication classes in settings.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': 
    [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        ...
    ],
}
```